# div => false is not working in CakepPHP input() FormHelper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the last version of cakephp, with the follow code I have to create a list of checkboxes.

```
echo $this->Form->input('regions', array(
    'type'        => 'select',
    'hiddenField' => false,
    'options'     => $regions,
    'multiple'    => 'checkbox',
    'div'         => false
));
```

the code works 90%, I mean... the list has been created BUT I still see `<div>`

This is the result:

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[regions][]" value="1" id="Regions1" /><label for="Regions1">AAAA</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[regions][]" value="2" id="Regions2" /><label for="Regions2">BBBB</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[regions][]" value="3" id="Regions3" /><label for="Regions3">CCCC</label></div>
```

The result I need is:

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[regions][]" value="1" id="Regions1" /><label for="Regions1">AAAA</label>
</li>
...
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `'div' => false`, your prevents creating a <div> around the whole input section (i.e. the set of checkboxes). But obviously you want to disable the div's around the option. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a way to disable this with Cake.

However, you can simulate the <li> items with some CSS trickery. Encapsulate the  inputs in a div with a special class (the opposite of what you are doing now), then use CSS to force using <li> styling:

In your CSS:

```
.box2li div
{
  display: list-item;
}
```

In your Cake view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('regions', array(
    'type'        => 'select',
    'hiddenField' => false,
    'options'     => $regions,
    'multiple'    => 'checkbox',
    'div'         => array ('class' => 'box2li')
));
```

Each checkbox is now preceded by a...

...bullet

Answer (score 1):

There should be a more simple way but you can always do it in the traditional way :)

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($regions)){
    echo '<li>'.
        $this->Form->input($value, 
             array(
                'type' => 'checkbox', 
                'name' => 'data[regions][]', 
                'div' => false,
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => false, 
                'after' => $this->Form->label($value, $value)
             ))
    .'</li>';
}
```

Not so beautiful, but works :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Form->Checkbox instead of Form->input

```js
$this->Form->checkbox('', array(
  'label' => false, 
  'div' => false,
  'class' => ''
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$this->Form->checkbox('', array(
  'label' => false, 
  'div' => false,
  'class' => ''
));
```

```js
$this->Form->checkbox('', array(
  'label' => false, 
  'div' => false,
  'class' => ''
));
```